# change return value of function with buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overrun

**x86 system**

I am trying to change the return value of a function. For example

```
int foo(){
   char buffer[12]; 
   gets(buffer);
   return 1;
}

int main(){
   int value;
   value = foo();
   return 0;
}
```

foo() always returns 1. I know that return values from functions are stored to %eax (so 1 is stored to %eax).Is there any way that i can reach and change %eax value?
I am thinking that this can't happen because %eax doesn't appear in the stack!Am I right?

Comment: `foo` always returns `1` because you `return 1;`. Figure out what you want to return and then `return the_value;`. In x86 assembly, arguments are provided to the callee on the stack, the return is returned to the caller in EAX (not on the stack).

Comment: I think he's trying to hack an existing program, not re-write the code.

Comment: Looking at it again. I think you are correct. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am not trying to "fix" my code. I am trying to change return value of foo runtime with buffer overflow

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to modify the value of `EAX` in that function through a buffer overflow for precisely the reason that you surmise.  How could potentially take over program execution, however, since you can overwrite the entire stack frame, including the saved frame pointer and return address.

How to accomplish this seems to be outside of the scope of your question, but it will be dependent on whether or not ASLR is in use, stack canaries are in use, a non-executable stack is in place, etc.